# отображение данных внутри переменных при отладке C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Увидел в видео, что у автора при отладке отображаются данные, которые находятся в переменных, понимаю, что надо что-то включить в настройках, но что именно? Или может это решарпер?
Вот скриншот, чтобы понять о чем я говорю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть не надо мышкой наводить на переменную, данные отображаются рядом с кодом (`idBefore=4`, `model = Count = 4`...)

Comment: Да, это вроде платный плагин ReSharper, если я ничего не путаю https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Debugging_Assistance.html?ysclid=l7hr238rcq992792599#searchable-datatips

Comment: @aepot, похоже на то, жаль, удобная вроде штука, но спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть хороший аналог. У меня стоит бесплатный [CodeRush for Visual Studio 2022](https://www.devexpress.com/products/coderush/?utm_source=VSIX%20Install&utm_medium=VSIX%20Install&utm_campaign=CodeRush%20VSIX%20Install&utm_content=CodeRush_MoreInformation) от DevExpress. Также подписывает переменные при пошаговой отладке.
[image: Пример]

Comment: Также есть встроенная фича в визуалке. При пошаговой отладке после инициализации переменной наводишь указатель на переменную и появляется попап со значением переменной (его можно зафиксировать, нажав на кнопку булавки)